# I can't initialize my array (MutableList) within a class in Android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, kotlin

I just started with Kotlin and Android studio.  When in the `MainActivity.kt` I do the following ...

```
var tafels: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = java.util.ArrayList()
tafels.add(mutableListOf<Int>(2, 2, 4))
```

... everything works fine. I can add elements to this `ArrayList`, as shown.

When I try to do the same in a new file, in a class I created, however, the code assist doesn't recognise `tafel` when I type it in, and therefore no suggestions come after I type `tafels`:

```
class TafelsSommen(){

    var tafels: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = java.util.ArrayList()            
    tafels.add(mutableListOf<Int>(2, 2, 4))
}
```

Why can't I add elements to `tafels` inside class `TafelsSommen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could make use of standard lib functions for creating your lists. The following is type safe whereas yours isn’t because the `ArrayList` did not specify its type parameter.

```
val tafels: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(2, 2, 4))
```

You're trying to invoke code, here adding an element to list, in the class body. This does not work. Wrap it into an `init` block or add it to the property declaration:

```
class TafelsSommen() {
    val tafels: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf())

    init {
        tafels.add(mutableListOf(2, 2, 4))
    }
}
```

Again, [here’s](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#class-members) how a class can be structured:

“Classes can contain”:

- Constructors and initializer blocks
- Functions
- Properties
- Nested and Inner Classes
- Object Declarations

No statement like yours allowed.

Comment: MutableList is not an ArrayList, so you can't initialize something declared as a MutableList as an ArrayList

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the quick responds!! This helps me understand it much better, thanks!

Comment: @Bram Mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem.